# Appcelerator and Javascript. Detect iOS 5

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.2 
iPhone Device family: iphone iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an app in Appcelerator for the iOS and I need to check for iOS5 so that I can do stuff in another way as for example 4.3.3. I tried to detect iOS5 with the below code but it does not work for my device with iOS 4.3.3. I think it is a decimal problem.

How can I do a check when decimals is involved in javascript?

if (Titanium.Platform.version < 5)

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 2):

`Titanium.Platform.version` is a string, so you'll need to split it and convert the first part to an integer:

```
var version = Titanium.Platform.version.split(".");
var major = parseInt(version[0]);
if (major < 5) ...
```